# @ symbol in PHP

Tags: php

What are the advantages of using `$exists = @$userID;` statement, compared to the longer notation of `if(isset($userID)){$exists = $userID; }else{$exists = false;}`

Is the `"@"` notation a lot faster, because I find it less readable ?

Comment: in short: you won't get an `Notice: Undefined variable: useriD` exeption if `@` is present and UserID is not set

Answer (score 1):

Apparently after a 5 second google search, it supresses error reporting.